# How to pass form values to bootstrap model form hidden fields

Tags: php, html, jquery

i need to pass form values to bootstrap model form hidden fields on form button click.
basically the button is form button that holds the value of pos_id from database and a hidden text field that holds pro_id from database and when use click "Apply" button a registration form in model is opened where i need to take input from user and also want to store hidden fields value to database along with user inputs

here is my code of form that i am submitting.

```php
<?php
    echo "<div class='mt-3'>          
        <table class='table table-striped'>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Apply For</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Project Name</th>
              <th>Type</th>
              <th>Last Date</th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>".$row['post_name'],"</td>
              <td>".$row['post_desc'],"</td>
              <td>".$row['proj_name'],"</td>
              <td>".$row['proj_type'],"</td>
              <td>".$row['last_date'],"</td>
              <td>
                <form id='post_apply' method='post' action=''>
                  <input type='hidden' value='".$row['proj_id'],"'","></input>
                  <button data-toggle='modal' data-target='#applymodal' type='button' name='apply_btn' value='".$row['post_id'],"'"," class='btn btn-success border float-right '>Apply</button>
                </form>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>";
    }
} 
else {
  echo "<p class='alert alert-danger text-center'>No Posts Found</p>";
    exit;
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

and model code is as:

```html
<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="applymodal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog " style="max-width:600px;">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header bg-danger  ">
        <h1 class="modal-title text-center" color="white">New Registration</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div id="modalmain" class="modal-body">
        <form class="form" action="signup.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <fieldset>

            <!-- display form error messages  -->
            <?php include(INCLUDE_PATH . "/layouts/messages.php") ?>

            <div class="form-group <?php echo isset($errors['firstname']) ? 'has-error' : '' ?>">
              <label class="control-label">Firs Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control form-control-sm">
              <?php if (isset($errors['firstname'])): ?>
              <span class="help-block"><?php echo $errors['firstname'] ?></span>
              <?php endif; ?>
              <?php echo $row['post_id'];?>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group <?php echo isset($errors['last_name']) ? 'has-error' : '' ?>">
              <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control form-control-sm">
              <?php if (isset($errors['last_name'])): ?>
              <span class="help-block"><?php echo $errors['last_name'] ?></span>
              <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group <?php echo isset($errors['mobile']) ? 'has-error' : '' ?>">
              <label class="control-label">Mobile</label>
              <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" class="form-control form-control-sm" data-inputmask=" 'mask' : '0399-9999999'" placeholder="Mobile">
              <?php if (isset($errors['mobile'])): ?>
              <span class="help-block"><?php echo $errors['mobile'] ?></span>
              <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group <?php echo isset($errors['username']) ? 'has-error' : '' ?>">
              <label class="control-label">CNIC Number</label>
              <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control form-control-sm" data-inputmask="'mask': '99999-9999999-9'" placeholder="14 Digits CNIC Number" required="yes">
              <?php if (isset($errors['username'])): ?>
              <span class="help-block"><?php echo $errors['username'] ?></span>
              <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group <?php echo isset($errors['email']) ? 'has-error' : '' ?>">
              <label class="control-label">Email</label>
              <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Email Address">
              <?php if (isset($errors['email'])): ?>
              <span class="help-block"><?php echo $errors['email'] ?></span>
              <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group <?php echo isset($errors['password']) ? 'has-error' : '' ?>">
              <label class="control-label">Password</label>
              <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control form-control-sm">
              <?php if (isset($errors['password'])): ?>
              <span class="help-block"><?php echo $errors['password'] ?></span>
              <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group <?php echo isset($errors['passwordConf']) ? 'has-error' : '' ?>">
              <label class="control-label">Password confirmation</label>
              <input type="password" name="passwordConf" class="form-control form-control-sm">
              <?php if (isset($errors['passwordConf'])): ?>
              <span class="help-block"><?php echo $errors['passwordConf'] ?></span>
              <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            
            <input type="hidden" value="$_POST['proj_id'];"></input>
            <input type="hidden" value="$_POST['post_id'];"></input>
            
            <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" name="signup_btn" class="btn btn-block btn-success ">Create Account</button>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <p class="text-start">Aready have an account? <a href="/online/login.php">Sign in</a></p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are missing name attribute on hidden inputs

Answer (score 0):

@salar zaidi: Thank you soo much for help.

This solution worked for me:

```js
$("#post_apply").click(function() {
  var proj = $(this).find("#proj_id").val();
  var post = $(this).find("#apply_btn").val();
  var postn = $(this).find("#post_name").val();

  $("#field_proj_id").val(proj)
  $("#field_post_id").val(post)
  $("#field_post_n").val(postn)  
});
```